# Elegant Solution to Returning a Default Template

Tags: c++, templates

Essentially, I'm wondering what is the most elegant way to return a template that is of null type or default type (or it is not possible and an error should be thrown)? How is it done in a professional environment?

I've wrote a simple program to express the problem I'm facing.

I've left a few comments to show my inelegant solution that doesn't resolve the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE_OF_CONTAINER = 10;

template<typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    Container();
    ~Container();

    void AddEntry(T Number);
    T& operator[](int Confirm);     // Method with problem
private:
    T** mElements;
    T* mDisposable;                 // My horrible solution that doesn't work

    int mSize;
};

int main()
{
    Container<int> container;

    container.AddEntry(10);
    container.AddEntry(50);
    container.AddEntry(100);
    container.AddEntry(1000);

    container[1] = 468468;

    cout << container[1] << endl;

    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

template<typename T>
Container<T>::Container()
{
    this->mElements = new T*[MAX_SIZE_OF_CONTAINER];
    this->mDisposable = new T(0);   // Set to default

    mSize = 0;
}

template<typename T>
Container<T>::~Container()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)
    {
        delete mElements[i];
    }

    delete mElements;
    delete mDisposable;
}

template<typename T>
void Container<T>::AddEntry(T Number)
{
    if (mSize < MAX_SIZE_OF_CONTAINER)
    {
        mElements[mSize] = new T(Number);
        mSize++;
    }
}

template<typename T>
T& Container<T>::operator[](int Index)
{
    if (Index < mSize)
        return *this->mElements[Index];
    else
        return *mDisposable;            // Works for types with a default type.
}
```

Comment: `T*` will suffice. No need to over-engineer.

Comment: Unreleated, but you don't delete `mElements` itself and `mDisposable` in destructor

Comment: There are several possibilities: `T*` ("C programming"); `std::optional<T>` ("functional programming"); throw an exception ("software engineering"); or call it "undefined behaviour" and leave the user to check first ("C++ committeering").

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm going to play around with the solutions and get back to here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I thought I would add an answer just in case people in the future view this question. Apologies in advance if this is not the correct protocol for this site. All credit to [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo).)

> There are several possibilities: T* ("C programming"); std::optional ("functional programming"); throw an exception ("software engineering"); or call it "undefined behaviour" and leave the user to check first ("C++ committeering"). - There are several possibilities: `T*` ("C programming"); `std::optional<T>` ("functional programming"); throw an exception ("software engineering"); or call it "undefined behaviour" and leave the user to check first ("C++ committeering"). – [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo)

I went with the software engineering solution because I'm a student of the course software engineering. This is by no means the answer to the question but this is the solution I went with for my program. Here is the updated "simple program" from the question with the solution implemented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

const int MAXSIZEOFCONTAINER = 10;

class OutOfRangeException : public out_of_range
{
public:
    OutOfRangeException() : out_of_range("Index out of range.")
    {
    }
};

class Container
{
public:
    Container();
    ~Container();

    void AddNumber(int Number);
    int& GetNumber(int Index);    
    int& operator[](int Confirm);

private:
    int** mElements;
    int mSize;
};

int main()
{
    Container Num;

    Num.AddNumber(10);
    Num.AddNumber(50);
    Num.AddNumber(100);
    Num.AddNumber(1000);

    try
    {
        Num[10] = 468468468;
    }
    catch (exception e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

Container::Container()
{
    this->mElements = new int * [MAXSIZEOFCONTAINER];

    mSize = 0;
}

Container::~Container()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)
    {
        delete mElements[i];
    }

    delete mElements;
}

void Container::AddNumber(int Number)
{
    if (mSize < MAXSIZEOFCONTAINER)
    {
        mElements[mSize] = new int(Number);
        mSize++;
    }
}

int& Container::GetNumber(int Index)
{
    if (mSize < MAXSIZEOFCONTAINER)
        return *mElements[Index];
}

int& Container::operator[](int Index)
{
    if (Index < mSize)
        return *this->mElements[Index];
    else
        throw OutOfRangeException();
}
```